# Rails: Setting attribute in after_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

I would like ActiveRecord to set some DB field automatically using callbacks.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   after_create :set_locale
   def set_locale
      self.locale = I18n.locale
   end
end
```

In ./script/console I do

```
p = Product.create
p
```

Field p.locale is not set. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Most likely Product.create is failing, so `after_create` is not being called. Take a look at `p.errors`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[before_create](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#M002141) is called before [Base.save](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002329), since your not saving its not getting called.

Edit:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_create :set_locale
   def set_locale
      self.locale = I18n.locale
   end
end
```

With this in your controller will work how you want it to.

```
@product = Product.create # before_create will be called and locale will be set for the new product
```

Comment: You have to call save for the callback to be called whether you put before_create or after_create. before_create is what you are looking for, but you must call save for it to do anything.

Comment: This answer is wrong. ActiveRecord::Base.create will trigger a save call and calling save again will not fix the problem.

Comment: The whole point of ActiveRecord::Base.create is to instantiate *and save* a model.

Comment: before_create can also be used to set other fields that were not collected on the initial form. For example, I helped write an oAuth implementation using Devise and Omniauth to integrate into an existing platform. Devise adds the field of username to the User DB Schema and we set that field before saving the new User with the User's email address.

Comment: @Joey Could you correct your answer & comment regarding calling `create()` won't trigger `after_create()`?

Answer (score 4):

Use `before_create` to set default values. Remember: `after_create` is fired *after* the save to the database. Using `after_create` will only initialize the values in memory, and will require *additional* save to commit the initialized values to the database.

Answer (score 2):

what Joey is saying is that after_create will not work.

use before_create